# How can I set journald settings for non-root users?

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

I have a bunch of services that run under non-root users automatically. I've modified my /etc/systemd/journald.conf to limit the maximum allowed filesize, but it doesn't work on systemd services that run under non-root users.

How can I tell my system to limit the journal entries for all services run under a non-root user to X amount of Megabytes for the journal?